# how to update checkbox in Room Database. The checkbox is not getting updated in room

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

**// Update Function in ViewModel class
I think the main problem is in viewmodel class as it is not letting it updated. I have tried many solution but none of them helped me

```
fun updateTask(task : ToDoItem, isChecked : Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch {
    val updateTask = task.copy(isCompleted = isChecked)
    repository.updateTask(updateTask)
    Log.d("Msg", updateTask.toString())
}
```

Adapter class

```
class TodoAdapter(private val listener : OnItemClick) : ListAdapter<ToDoItem, TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>(DiffCallBack()){

    inner class TodoViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        private val tvTask: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTask)
        private val checkBox: CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)

        init {
            checkBox.setOnClickListener{
                val position = adapterPosition
                if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    val task = getItem(position)
                    listener.onCheckBoxClick(task, checkBox.isChecked)
                }
            }
        }

        fun bind(item: ToDoItem) {
            tvTask.text = item.task
            checkBox.isChecked = item.isCompleted
            tvTask.paint.isStrikeThruText = item.isCompleted
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        val viewHolder = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.task_layout, parent, false)
        return TodoViewHolder(viewHolder)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    interface OnItemClick{
        fun onCheckBoxClick(task : ToDoItem, isChecked : Boolean)
    }
}


class DiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ToDoItem>(){
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ToDoItem, newItem: ToDoItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ToDoItem, newItem: ToDoItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }
```

// Main Activity class

In main I implemented the Interface which calls the update() in viewModel

```
    mAdapter = TodoAdapter(this)
    binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,
             ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application))[ToDoViewModel::class.java]
    viewModel.tasks.observe(this, Observer {
        mAdapter.submitList(it)
    })
}

override fun onCheckBoxClick(task: ToDoItem, isChecked: Boolean) {
    viewModel.updateTask(task, isChecked)
}
```

**Repository Class**

```
suspend fun updateTask(task : ToDoItem){
        dao.updateTask(task)
    }
```

**Dao class**

```
 @Update
    suspend fun updateTask(task : ToDoItem)
```

**Data class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "todo_table")
data class ToDoItem (
    val task : String,
    var isCompleted : Boolean = false
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id : Int = 0
}
```

Comment: Can you try logging the `id`'s of all the items in your list that you're getting from Room? I have never seen a Room Entity where the `id` (or any of the columns) is not in the constructor. I thought Room only works with constructor parameters, which would mean every item retrieved from Room incorrectly has an `id` of 0 for this Entity.

Comment: I think I am getting what you are trying to say. So I update as you told and this time it really worked. Thank very much sir for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the issue. Might not be the only problem.

Your implementation of `areContentsTheSame` is incorrect. You should be comparing all properties that are visible in the RecycleView. In this case, it is `task` and `isCompleted`. You are only comparing the IDs, so DiffUtil doesn’t detect any change when you change the value of `isCompleted` and the check box won’t be updated.

Usually, we use a `data` class for the type of the items in the list, and then all you need to do is

```
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ToDoItem, newItem: ToDoItem) =
    oldItem == newItem
```

Comment: Thank you for answering to my problem. I did as you told to update the function. But it is still not getting updated. But by just adding this line it is now working fine  "task.isCompleted = isChecked | repository.updateTask(task)". I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: I would have to see the code for how you declare and manage your `viewModel.tasks` property to see why. That code is not going to work correctly when you *un*check boxes.